# MVC 4 with jquery ui moving between tabs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-tabs

I have two links in my layout. log in and register. both have views that shows tabs. When I click on login link i redirect to and set active tab to 0

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login In","Login","Account")
```

same for register I redirect to and set active: 1 (Works fine)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Regisrter","Register","Account")
```

[image]

my question, When i am on the login view and I click on register tab how do I go to register view? and same when I am on register view and i click on login tab how do I redirect to the login page?

my login view:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 0 });
});
</script>

 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">login</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2">Register</a></li>        
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    //controls here
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
</div>
```

register view:

```
<script>
   $(function () {
       $("#tabs").tabs({ active: 1 });
});
</script>

 <div id="tabs">
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">login</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tabs-2">Register</a></li>        
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
  //controls here
</div>
```

I tried to change the register link on the login view to:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Regisrter","Register","Account")</li>
```

but it is not redirecting to the register view

basically I am trying to make it work like https://stackoverflow.com/users/login Log in and Sign up works

How do I make it work, thank you, suggestions, thank you

Comment: if you want to keep url of both page different than their is no use of jquery ui tab. you can simply show another tab as an hyperlink and keeping the same structure on opposite page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Html.ActionLink You can try with partial View:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">

             $(function () {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            });
        </script>
                        <div id="tabs">
                           <ul>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Create An Account</a></li>
                          </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                         @Html.Partial("_Login", Model.LoginModel)
                    </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                          @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.RegisterModel)

                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, but if I add Partial View, the url doesnt change so it shows both views(pages) /login and /register on the same page

Comment: Yep, and why you need to change url you should create form on both partial views and post it

Comment: i was just thinking in case someone bookmarks specific page, as I will have more tabs. ...It might not be the right approach. probably need to rethink of the right approach

Comment: yeah you are right ,and when you get it plz update the thread